# How to make xUnit fail if no Assert executed?

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

Basically I need to make xUnit fail by default.
So this fails:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{

}
```

Comment: What's the reason for this? You could write another unit test that parses all your test files and checks for an `Assert` in each test.

Comment: I want to check if one of subsequent methods is executed. So I put Assert in them. Now I need to figure if non of them is executed.

Comment: I'd like this too. For me I'd like to braindump all the tests I know are the minimum coverage to ensure a feature behaves the way I want. This way I know I'm not done until it's all green.